# How to copy S3 object with special character in key

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have objects in an S3 bucket, and I do not have control over the names of the keys. Some of these keys have special characters and AWS SDK does not like them.

For example, one object key is: `folder/‍Johnson, Scott to JKL-Discovery.pdf`, it might look fine at first glance, but if I URL encode it: `folder%2F%E2%80%8DJohnson%2C+Scott+to+JKL-Discovery.pdf`, you can see that after `folder/` (or `folder%2F` when encoded) there is a random sequence of characters `%E2%80%8D` before `Johnson`.

It is unclear where these characters come from, however, I need to be able to handle this use case. When I try to make a copy of this object using the Node.js AWS SDK,

```
const copyParams = {
    Bucket,
    CopySource,
    Key : `folder/‍Johnson, Scott to JKL-Discovery.pdf`
  };
  let metadata = await s3.copyObject(copyParams).promise();
```

It fails and can't find the object, if I `encodeURI()` the key, it also fails.

How can I deal with this?

**DO NOT SUGGEST I CHANGE THE ALLOWED CHARACTERS IN THE KEY NAME. I DO NOT HAVE CONTROL OVER THIS**

Comment: The issue you’re facing is because you are not following the S3 Object Key Naming Guidelines [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-key-guidelines). Its strongly recommended that you manage your keynames as per the documentation.

Comment: @hephalump I do not care. I say in bold letters, I do not have control. I am looking for a solution with the current set of problems.

Comment: Good luck, friend!

Comment: Have you tried using the SDK to obtain a listing of the bucket? It will return the _exact_ keys of the objects. You can then use the key to copy the object. No need to encode anything, just use the exact value that the bucket listing provided.

Comment: @John the problem is not all objects need to be copied, only a subset of the bucket. I am given a list of keys that need to be copied, these keys are obtained when uploading the file, so they are the exact key.

Comment: I am suggesting that you obtain a listing of the bucket to get the "real" key of the object. The one you have been using is not in the right format, or contains incorrect characters. This might be the result of how they are providing you the filenames.

Comment: Also, what appears in the bucket access log for the failed copy request?

Comment: The only thing you can do - is just change the keys - documentation states that it cannot handle them properly and probably will not..  If you really need to have the key saved, you can use the oryginal name, base64 it, and that base64 stirng use as key.

Answer (score 3):

Faced the same problem but with PHP. `copyObject()` method is automatically encoding destination parameters (Bucket and Key) parameters, but not source parameter (CopySource) so it has to be encoded manually. In php it looks like this:

```
  $s3->copyObject([
    'Bucket' => $targetBucket,
    'Key' => $targetFilePath,
    'CopySource' => $s3::encodeKey("{$sourceBucket}/{$sourceFilePath}"),
  ]);
```

I'm not familiar with node.js but there should also exist that `encodeKey()` method that can be used?

Comment: I couldn't find the equivalent in the JS SDK, but based on [the PHP implementation](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/cae6d304776a08497b2edc49a05cf4487089b6dc/src/S3/S3Client.php#L510): `encodeKey = key => encodeURIComponent(key).replace("%2F", "/")`

Comment: `rawurlencode($filename)` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

trying your string, there's a tricky 'zero width space' unicode char...
[http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=342+200+213&mode=obytes](http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/%7Erichard/utf-8.cgi?input=342+200+213&mode=obytes)

I would sanitize the string removing unicode chars and then proceding with url encoding as requested by official docs.

```
encodeURI('folder/‍johnson, Scott to JKL-Discovery.pdf'.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]/g, ""))
```